# Volume edited by systemd-coredump docker

Tags: docker, permissions, volume

I'm trying to make a Symfony project running in docker container.
So, there is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version:  '3.7'
services:
    mariadb:
        image: ${MARIADB_VERSION}
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - ${PORTS_MARIADB}
        volumes:
            - './db/:/var/lib/mysql'
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - './app/:/usr/src/app'
        restart: on-failure
        user: 1000:1000
    nginx:
        image: ${NGINX_VERSION}
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
            - './app/public/:/usr/src/app' 
            - './docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro'
        ports:
            - ${PORTS_NGINX}
        depends_on:
            - php
```

I start my container like this (with non-root user):

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

So, at this point, all is ok but, If I want to re-build my docker container:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose build
```

The volume ./db (of mariadb) have his permissions set to systemd-coredump:findl users (findl is mine)
So, I have this error when I try to build the container:

[image]

Why the permissions to the volume /db are set to another user... ?

Regards

Comment: You found any answer ?

Answer (score 1):

As a result of [this Github issue reply](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/392#issuecomment-408110910), I was able to fix my issues and move on. Basically, take the temporary portion of your volume and add it to `.dockerignore`. The commenter does a much better explanation of why it works than I would ever be able to muster here, but if this gets you (or anyone else who runs into this issue) farther along, then so be it.